# How to thin out data in zoo

Tags: r, filtering, time-series, thin, zoo

Is there a function that let me thin out my data (time-series as zoo)?

The Example would be

```
mytime<-as.POSIXct(paste("2013-07-09 12:", c(1:59), sep=""))
mydata<-EuStockMarkets[1:59]
myts<-zoo(mydata, mytime)
```

I search a function that returns an irregular timeseries with just those data, that are different to the previous timestep by lets say ten points.

Any idea with zoo??

Thank you

Bastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `subset`:

```
> subset(myts, diff(myts) > 10)
2013-07-09 12:04:00 2013-07-09 12:07:00 2013-07-09 12:10:00 2013-07-09 12:22:00 
            1621.04             1630.75             1645.89             1616.67 
2013-07-09 12:28:00 2013-07-09 12:32:00 2013-07-09 12:37:00 2013-07-09 12:38:00 
            1631.87             1650.43             1524.28             1603.65 
2013-07-09 12:39:00 2013-07-09 12:40:00 2013-07-09 12:41:00 
            1622.49             1636.68             1652.10
```

Use `abs(diff(myts))` if either direction is needed.